# sorting various headings in rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

A friend of mine has given me his excel collection of recipies. He has around 500 recipies which has split into each letter on a different sheet. 
He wants me to then sort the recpies for each letter into alphabetical order as well.

He just has the recipies listed one after the other. All information starting in the first column. 
Whenever I click sort - it sorts everything so it jumbles up the method, ingredients and headings. 
I have tried formatting as a table but this doesnt work either. 
How do I sort each recipie as a whole rather than each line in the recipe? 
I have been watching youtube videos and googling this for 2 days now but it doesnt seem possible? 
Do I need to re-do the whole spread sheet? I think it has taken him a year or so to get this all into 1 document. 
Note he is an elderly patient of mine in an aged care home and I have told him I will help sort it.

Thank you

Comment: If would be helpful to have sample data. You can upload screen caps to http://imgur.com and link to them here

Comment: Please do save an example as a CSV file, grab several rows of data with header row, then post them on a public text hosting site like http://pastebin.com ; it will be far easier than trying to figure out a screenshot on imgur.com

Comment: It's quit interesting,,, but what we need is, either sample data or small portion of the WB to examine and fix it,, better [Edit] your post & upload sample data or share the link via Dropbox or Google Drive !! Or if possible just Mail me, find my ID with profile☺

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a sorting activity.. make sure you have a backup file before you edit/try anything. ( :

Idea : (1)extract all sheet name , use it to (2)produce a new sorted (sheet) list. With that list, (3)create an "Index page" with hyperlinks to each sheet/recipe.

**(1) extract all sheet name**

ref : https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/3-quick-ways-to-get-a-list-of-all-worksheet-names-in-an-excel-workbook/

in the recipe workbook, create a new sheet named "INDEX", and do "Method 2: List with Formula" in the link mentioned. You should get the 500 sheet names just by completing this.

**(2)produce a new sorted (sheet) list.**

Upon completion, put =row() in C1 and drag downwards.

Then copy the list (500 sheet names) in column b (result from step 1), and paste as text in column d. Then select all the 500 names in column d > r-click > sort A-Z.  (now we have all the sheet names sorted in D1:D500)

**(3)create an "Index page" with hyperlinks to each sheet/recipe.**

In this step, I'll leave the "beautification" to you, but here is the core : convert all sheetnames to clickable hyperlink, and the arrange each of the completed link in a presentable order. (Once this is all over we can always hide the source column)

In E1 put

```
=HYPERLINK(C1&"!A1",C1)
```

and drag downwards. Test those hyperlink just to make sure it works. Save the file.

Since the list (column e) is sorted, you can now just drag and drop all the 'produced' link with "A","B","C" headings and its recipe/sheet name (This is the "beautification" part). Do it in column G and above so that you can hide column a to e later.

Note : the hyperlink cell must be drag'n'dropped for it to work. don't worry about loosing the 'original' link in column e since it can always be reproduced by repeating the above formula step.

Please share if it works/not. ( :

Hope it helps